# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'join' using asp.net part 2

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, database

take note im still a beginner in databases but willing to learn! This question is related to [Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'JOIN'. using asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44986597/incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-join-using-asp-net). But this time, i want to know how to update a data from database. I've tried this code but it is giving me an error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'JOIN'". Kindly help me on solving this one.

```
string queryGuitarItems = "UPDATE stringInstrumentItem JOIN brand ON stringInstrumentItem.brandId = brand.brandId SET stringInstrumentItem.brandId = @brandId IN (SELECT brand.brandId FROM brand WHERE name = @oldBrandName";
    using (SqlConnection connectionGuitarItems = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["musicStoreConnection"].ToString()))
    {
        using (SqlCommand commandGuitarItems = new SqlCommand(queryGuitarItems, connectionGuitarItems))
        {
            List<SqlParameter> parameterGuitarItems = new List<SqlParameter>();
            parameterGuitarItems.Add(new SqlParameter("@brandId", newName.Text));
            parameterGuitarItems.Add(new SqlParameter("@oldBrandName", oldName));

            connectionGuitarItems.Open();
            GetParameterGuitarItems(commandGuitarItems,parameterGuitarItems.ToArray());
            commandGuitarItems.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connectionGuitarItems.Close();
            commandGuitarItems.Parameters.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Here is also the code for GerParameterGuitarItems method:

```
public void GetParameterGuitarItems(SqlCommand command, params SqlParameter[] parameterGuitarItems)
{
    if (parameterGuitarItems != null && parameterGuitarItems.Any())
    {
        command.Parameters.AddRange(parameterGuitarItems);
    }
}
```

Additional Info:

**Table stringInstrumentItem(The column brandId is the foreign key and references the primary key of table brand, which is also named brandId):**

itemId     brandId     model
1             1               xyz
2             1               abc
3             2               hjk

**Table brand(which has the primary key called brandId that is referencing by the table strinInstrumentItem):**

brandId     name     image
1             Ibanez       xyz.jpg
2             Fender       abc.jpg
3             Gibson       hjk.jpg

**Main goal is to update the column called name in table brand through my gridview. Like for example in brandId#1, name is equals to Ibanez, and I want to change it to Jackson. It should be able to work without the exception error. How to query this one?**

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: First people want to delete from joined tables, now they want to update on them. Does anyone have an SQL manual?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess that you are using SQL Server (something about the c# tag).  If so, the correct syntax is:

```
UPDATE sii
    SET brandId = @brandId
    FROM stringInstrumentItem sii JOIN
         brand b
         ON sii.brandId = b.brandId
    WHERE b.brandId IN (SELECT b2.brandId FROM brand b2 WHERE b2.name = @oldBrandName);
```

If I understand what you are trying to do, then this is over-complicated, and this suffices:

```
UPDATE sii
    SET brandId = @brandId
    FROM stringInstrumentItem sii 
    WHERE sii.brandId IN (SELECT b.brandId FROM brand b WHERE b.name = @oldBrandName);
```

Or, in a version that should work in any database:

```
UPDATE stringInstrumentItem
    SET brandId = @brandId
    WHERE brandId IN (SELECT b.brandId FROM brand b WHERE b.name = @oldBrandName);
```

Comment: i have tried all your solutions. weirdly enough it would give me this error "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Dean' to data type int.". But when i run my website again and check my gridview, it did update the data. Why is it giving me this error?

Comment: Obviously, the error is caused because a field that contains the string `'Dean'` is being treated as an int.  This question doesn't have enough information to answer that question.  You should first check the parameters to see if they have the right types.

Comment: what i've realized is i don't need the SET brandId = @brandId in the query. I tried doing the second option in this way "UPDATE sii FROM stringInstrumentItem sii WHERE sii.brandId IN (SELECT b.brandId FROM brand b WHERE b.name = @oldBrandName);". But this time, it says incorrect syntax near 'FROM'. how to modify this?

Comment: @RockStar . . . If you are not setting anything, why are you using an `update`?